# Como pegar o this.data de um input com onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funções

Estou precisando pegar os dados de um input com javascript. Desta forma, criei uma função atualizaAdicionados(e), porém não consigo pegar o elemento data do input.

```js
function atualizaAdicionados(e){
        console.log(e.value);
        console.log(e.data('id'));
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  class="valor" name="valor_2" value="125.00" data-id="2" id="valor_2" onkeyup="atualizaAdicionados(this)">
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ou dar outra sugestão?

OBS.: Acredito que não conseguirei trabalhar com o campo ID do input, pois terão vários inputs que irei inserir no banco de dados (como se fossem produtos de uma venda), então cada id será valor_ID. O que preciso é pegar o ID apenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `getAttribute` para obter o valor dos atributos: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```js
function atualizaAdicionados(e){
        console.log(e.value);
        console.log(e.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  class="valor" name="valor_2" value="125.00" data-id="2" id="valor_2" onkeyup="atualizaAdicionados(this)">
```

Comment: `e.dataset.id` é também uma opção.

Comment: sim @v.Santos é uma opção. Eu gosto mais do `getAttribute` porque serve para qualquer atributo diferente de "data-*", seria possível ser por exemplo "id-alternativo", o que não seria possível com `dataset`

Comment: Me ajudou, muito obrigado!